# How does threading affect the print function and when it is called (Java)

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, notify

I'm learning concurrency and I'm not quite certain as to why the output changes when I move the `printSuccess` function outside the `synchronized` block

Ive read the Oracle concurrency documentation and enough SO threads to understand the basic concepts and functionality at play. However, I can't explain this effect.

```
class ThreadTesting extends Thread {
    volatile static int turn = 1;
    public int id;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(ThreadTesting.class.getName());

    public ThreadTesting(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void run() {
        synchronized(this) {
            if(id != turn) {
                try {
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    LOGGER.info("Interrupted: " + id);
                }
            }
            printSuccess(id);
        }

    }

    public void printSuccess(int id) {
        turn++;
        System.out.println("Done:" + id);

        notifyAll();
    }
```

I'm initiallizing a set of the above objects (with ids 1-n) and calling `.start()` on each. I expect that they would all print out their id's in order. However the result changes unexpectedly if I move the `printSuccess()` function outside the `synchronized` block.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You lock on the individual threads. You should lock on a common lock. Also `notifyAll()` should throw an exception when that you don't hold the monitor if you move `printSuccess` out.

Comment: How does the behavior change?

Comment: @JohannesKuhn you mean lock on a mutex or something similar?

Comment: Lock on an object. Like `synchronized(lock)`, where `lock` is a `static final Object lock = new Object();`.